# Fixed size std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stack

I'm currently in the process of changing the way I access my data structures, and I'm reviewing one of two solutions in the general case for vectors of vectors.

My incentive is simple; I want cache locality without giving up my interfaces.

I know the max-size of my vectors at compile time, but they won't always be reaching the max. Common case is about 80%, and the total size of each vector is to be relatively small.
If I reach that max, I have made an error in logic somewhere, and want it to throw an error.

The first solution that came to mind, was to use a Pool allocator with std::vector, seemed like a good idea, but maybe a bit messy; having not used allocators properly before, I wasn't too sure of the solution. I'm not much of a fan for storing the data separate to its owners, and I want the implementation to be as transparent as possible.

The second solution works great for me at the moment, but I want to make it a little bit less in line. At the moment, it is thus:

```
class Foo {
public:
        std::array<Bar, 10> bars;
        size_t used;

        // std::vector<Bar> bars; // reserved to 10... maybe

        void add(int var1, int var2) {
                if (used >= bars.size()) throw "Error";
                bars[used] = Bar(var1, var2);
                ++used;

                // std::vector alternative
                // bars.push_back(Bar(var1, var2));
        }
        void remove(size_t idx) {
                bars[idx] = bars.back();
                --used;

                // bars.back().~Bar(); // should happen, not sure if safe

                // std::vector alternative
                // bars[idx] = bars.back();
                // bars.pop_back();
        }
}
```

Which, as mentioned, works great. However, if I wanted to move this solution elsewhere, I'd rather not have to implement it again, and have proper semantics in terms of destruction (similar to that of an *actual* vector).

So, I was wondering what a good solution could be? Currently, I've started wrapping an `std::array`, but it is starting to get messy, and I'm sure this is solved problem.

Comment: By letting your interfaces take a vector, which they cannot add to, you break them. They should not take a vector in the first place but array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: At the moment, I am using a `std::vector` with the necessary space reserved. The point is they can add/remove at their will, but *should* never go over the max limit. This isn't strictly enforced at the moment, as it doesn't really matter, its just something I can take advantage of.

Comment: So I guess "change your interface" is not a desirable solution?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, given the current switch over effort between solutions is simply changing to the `std::array` from `std::vector` and adding a count for the number of elements used; I was hoping to not have to do anything more; but if I want to do this elsewhere in future, this would be a great asset to use; as I know many cases where I know the max size at runtime, wanting the flexibility of a vector, but the locality of an array (especially if encapsulated in an object, among 1000's of others which are iterated often, therein thrashing the cache if allocated everywhere).

Comment: Added commented out code to the implementation example for what the code looks like using an `std::vector`.

Comment: Your use of `decltype` is fine; that's a sensible style for a wrapper template.  Your use of `throw` is problematic; surely you can throw proper exceptions? Your calling destructors (`this->back().~T();`) is *wrong*; you should be keeping the elements in a valid state and using `this->back() = T()` to reset to a default-initialized state.

Comment: Also, your `back()` should return `m_array[m_size - 1]`; it's not the same as `*end()`.

Comment: @ecatmur that code is completely untested, I just did it quickly to get a rough idea how much code I'm going to have to write, and consequently, test for robustness in some way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [link](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/tag/auto_buffer/) for several options for fixed-size data structures with a vector-like interface. In particular, `boost::auto_buffer` and `eastl::fixed_vector` seem viable options for your code.

Yet another alternative is to use Hinnant's [stack allocator](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) with the regular `std::vector`, but MSVC++ has some trouble compiling it.

Comment: That site is now dead/archived/protected.

Comment: @J.Hirsch Thanks, FTFY :)

Comment: 'preciate it. I couldn't get there at work; such a pain with heavily filtered sites.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a MultiArray class intended for this purpose.